# ionic publishing android apk signing error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When i run jarsigner, it gives timestamp error.

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

Error:

```
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2044-04-04) or after any future revocation date.
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding "-tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com" to the end of the commad solved the problem.

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk alias_name -tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com
```